# How configure stock mail with MobileIron?

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-nexus, exchange

MobileIron app doesn't show my samsung galaxy nexus stock mail app. But it does shows [TouchDown for Smartphones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nitrodesk.droid20.nitroid) . TouchDown experience is not up to the level of the stock app.

How can i configure MobileIron to work with my Stock mail app. My device is rooted and running CM11 Snapshot M4  on PA Gapps.